# No component found with scheme

Tags: docker, apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

This is really bizarre.

I've got 4 docker instances.  The Dockers are running Fuse 7.3 and AMQ.

They're identical, except for a few config variables.  I've diff'ed the `/etc/` folders, and there's nothing about the config that would cause this.

Fuse logs startup is identical.

My new service however, built in Jenkins, installed to the host volume of each one, only works in 1 of the 4 instances.

So, practically identical dockers, absolutely identical jar file.
And 3 of the 4 complain:

```
 Failed to resolve endpoint: artemis://queue:authRequest due to: No component found with scheme: artemis
```

I'm defining the beans:

```xml
<bean id="artemisConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory">
    <argument value="${activeMq.Uri}"/>
    <argument value="${activeMq.userName}"/>
    <argument value="${activeMq.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="artemis" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="artemisConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And the route is:

```xml
<camel:route id="proxyqueue">  
    <camel:from uri="artemis:queue:authRequest"/>  
    <camel:to uri="log:input?showAll=true&amp;level=INFO"/>
    <camel:to uri="{{auth.uri}}"/>
</camel:route>
```

`auth.uri` is the same for all.
The same setup works for a dozen other jars.  What the hell.  I restarted all the dockers.   1 of 4 works.  I tried with `activemq:` instead of `artemis:`, same thing.  Compared all the features in Fuse.  All the same. Same versions.

Before the error, the broken ones have this:

```
No matching service for optional OSGi service reference (&(component=artemis)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))
```

While the working one has this:

```
Created ClientConnectionManager org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager@10fe02ef
```

Comment: This issue doesn't seem directly related to anything within Artemis' control so I'm removing the `activemq-artemis` tag.

Comment: Ok, well I restarted all the dockers, and now a different one is working.  So it's likely to do with karaf startup sequence.  But it's still bizarre.

Comment: So I increased the time between loading the features and installing my services, and it's gone up to 4 out of 4 services running.  Going to try replicate results a few more times. What I don't understand is why, if I install my service, presumably before all the features are loaded, does it permanently mess up my OSGi and its chances of installing that service?  Once I get this 'no component found with scheme: artemis' message, there's no fixing it.

Comment: Ok tried again, same long delay between loading features and services, and down to 2/4.  And it's only this service.  OSGi is black magic.

Comment: Ended up rewriting in code instead of camel xml, and it worked.  For some reason, something in the OSGi wiring goes wrong half the time, so that org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver either resolves camel-http4 for my service, or it doesn't, when it's in the XML.  Oh well. Workaround is to not use activemq to camel-http4 XML DSL.

Answer (score 0):

It's a race condition, sometimes your integration starts first than artemis, so the scheme is not resolved, hence the error.  Please update your import section on the pom, with a reference to the artemis library, in general any library you use.  this is my example with camel-beanio:

```html
<!-- to generate the MANIFEST-FILE of the bundle -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.bundle.plugin.version}</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.name}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
      <Private-Package>com.mycustomer.*</Private-Package>
      <Import-Package>           
        io.fabric8.zookeeper,
        org.apache.camel.spi,
        org.beanio,       
        *
      </Import-Package>      
      <Export-Service>${camel.osgi.export.service}</Export-Service>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Use Maven central https://search.maven.org/ to get the exact dependencies for the version of your problematic library